# Graphql filter function returning all instead of specified ones

Tags: javascript, lodash, graphql

I wanna filter graphql query  by giving arguments, but the problem is that even if in filter variables is specified the result is the all items. I'm using functions from lodash.

This is my filter function

```
export const resolvers = {
Query: {
    // allItems: (_, { value }) => getAllLinks().then(result => filter(result, {value: value})),
    allItems: (_, { value }) => getAllLinks()
        .then(result => filter(result, val => val.custom_attributes
            .filter(customVal =>
                customVal.attribute_code === 'category_ids' && isEqual(customVal.value , value) 
            ))),
    // allItems: (_, { value }) => getAllLinks().then(result => console.log(result)),
},
```

The most mindtwist thing for me is that, if I'll add

```
customVal.attribute_code === 'category_ids' && isEqual(customVal.value , value)
 ? console.log(customVal)
 : null
```

log will return me correct number of objects. That's my schema.

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Item  {
        id: ID!
        name: String
        price: Float
        custom_attributes: [CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES]
    }

    union CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES = CustomString | CustomArray 

   type CustomString {
    attribute_code: String
    value: String
  }

  type CustomArray {
    attribute_code: String
    value: [String]

  } 

  type Query {
    allItems(value : [String]): [Item]!

  }
`;
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` function iterates over each item in an array and returns a new array with the filtered items. If no items where found, it returns an empty array. **An empty array evaluates as `truthy`**.

In your case, the outer filter filters the links (`result`). Each link that is evaluated by the outer filter function as `truthy` will be returned.
The outer filter function uses the result of the inner filter, which is always an array, sometimes an empty one, but always a `truthy` value (provided no exception was thrown). In other words, the outer filter function will always return all links.

Your `console.log` does log the items correctly because the code is executed even if we know it has no effect on the outer filter's result.

### A Possible Solution

If you replace the inner call to `val.custom_attributes.filter` with `val.custom_attributes.find` then the inner find function will either return the `custom_attribute` which is an object and therefore `truthy` or it will return `undefined` if no item matches the criteria. Since `undefined` is `falsy` the outer filter function will not return items without the relevant custom attribute in the final result.

Comment: You're right, I keep mistaking filter with find. Thank for help.
Now I have another question, because I'm using `isEqual` function that compare the variable given in argument in query with the field and returns fields which contains only that string from variables. But what if I would want to return the fields if they contain the variables? I mean, now if variable is `["3", "5"]` and value field has `["3", "5", "7"] it will not return this field, but it should. Is there some other function in lodash?

Comment: Sure, glad to help. About your second question, I'm not sure I understood, could you open a new question with an example of what you are trying to do? It is quite difficult to read it in a comment format. And maybe others will see it and be able to help too.

Comment: Please don't update your question here. The accepted format in this site is one question per post.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that :)